# cast a string value in NSDictionary to long make app crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a NSDictionary object get from server API. data is like this,

> "filesize_mp3":"60488"

when I use following code to retrieve file size, app crashes.  obj.filesize is in long type.

```
obj.filesize = [[dict objectForKey:@"filesize_mp3"] longValue],
```

lldb console,

```
2014-07-22 12:50:14.643 YouVoiceNews[2019:60b] -[__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bf8e10
2014-07-22 12:50:14.644 YouVoiceNews[2019:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9bf8e10'
```

but when I use

```
obj.filesize = (long)[dict objectForKey:@"filesize_mp3"];
```

everything is fine.

so my question is what's the differences between above 2 ways. why first one cause app crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the error. `NSString` doesn't have a method named `longValue`. See the docs for `NSString`.

Comment: one doesn't work with warning and one doesn't work without warning.

Comment: Your second line of code does not do what you think it does. It is completely wrong despite the lack of a crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Xcode's intelligent sense shows a longValue method. I should pay more attention on doc. change to longLongValue or integerValue is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**: *what's the differences between above 2 ways?*

1. The first approach attempts to send the message `-longValue` to the object stored at key @"filesize_mp3"
2. The second approach attempts to cast the pointer to the object stored at key @"filesize_mp3"

**Answer to question 2**: *why does the first one cause the app to crash?*

1. The object stored at key @"filesize_mp3" is a `NSString`, and `-longValue` is an invalid selector. The reason the code compiled in the first place is because `[dict objectForKey:@"filesize_mp3"]` is not typed (it's an `id`), and for convenience `id` will accept any selector at compilation time. A slightly more conservative approach is provided below ; casting the object to a `NSString` will not allow `[filesizeStr longValue]`.
2. The second approach does not crash because you are simply casting a pointer into a long. While it does not give you anything of interest, it is a valid operation.

**Answer to the question you did not ask**: *What should I have done?*

Your dictionary contains `NSString`, not `NSNumber` nor int or long. A dictionary is a collection of`NSObject`. Thus you must convert these strings into `int`, `long` or whatever format you see fit.

```
NSString * filesizeStr = [dict objectForKey:@"filesize_mp3"];
obj.filesize = [filesizeStr longLongValue];
```

Comment: Any thoughts on casting the assigned value on the second line like this: `obj.filesize = (long) [filesizeStr longLongValue];`? (I'm assuming that `filesizeStr` is a `long`, and that the values will always fit into a long).